# Plot a graph without NA's

Tags: r

```
Apartment_no <- c('1-SV','1-SH','3-SV','3-SH','5-SV','5-SH','7-SV','7-SH')
January <- c('', '', '3','5','9','','15','19')
February <- c('5', '', '3','5','','15','','19')
March <- c('5', '', '3','5','16','15','7','')
April <- c('', '', '3','5','','15','','19')
May <- c('', '8', '3','5','','15','','19')
June <- c('12', '', '','5','','15','','19')
July <- c('5', '', '3','5','','15','','19')
August <- c('51', '', '3','','','15','','19')
September <- c('5', '', '3','5','','15','','19')
October <- c('57', '', '','5','','15','','19')
November <- c('5', '', '','5','','21','','19')
December <- c('', '', '33','5','','15','','19')
Heatmeters <- data.frame(Apartment_no,January,February,March
                         ,April,May,June,July,August,September,August,November,December)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
Heatmeters %>% 
  select(Apartment_no,January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,August,November,December)  
#>   Apartment_no January February March April May June July August September
#> 1         1-SV                5     5             12    5     51         5
#> 2         1-SH                                8                           
#> 3         3-SV       3        3     3     3   3         3      3         3
#> 4         3-SH       5        5     5     5   5    5    5                5
#> 5         5-SV       9             16                                     
#> 6         5-SH               15    15    15  15   15   15     15        15
#> 7         7-SV      15              7                                     
#> 8         7-SH      19       19          19  19   19   19     19        19
#>   November December
#> 1        5         
#> 2                  
#> 3                33
#> 4        5        5
#> 5                  
#> 6       21       15
#> 7                  
#> 8       19       19
```

I am given certain apartment no's along with the data for each month. For some of the months the data is not given so there are na's. How to avoid these na's while plotting the data in the graph.
PS: Apartment no is a character column however the others are numeric. I tried the following code but it didn't work out:

```
plot(data=na.omit(Heatmeters)as.factor(Apartment_no), January,data=Heatmeters)
```

& is it possible to plot data for all the months in one graph. I actually want only those apartments to appear on the graph which have the data corresponding to any month.

Comment: It's unclear how exactly you want to plot this. As it stands, the NAs you're talking about aren't in your data, and something seems to be missing in the line of `plot` code, because that syntax isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

Your data contains `''` which is an empty string rather than `NA`. If you explicitly set `''` to `NA` and also change the month data to be numeric, plotting produces a result. I'm assuming this sort of plot is what you want.

Here's some code.

```
Heatmeters = data.frame(
    Apartment_no = c('1-SV','1-SH','3-SV','3-SH','5-SV','5-SH','7-SV','7-SH'),
    January = c('', '', '3','5','9','','15','19'),
    February = c('5', '', '3','5','','15','','19'),
    March = c('5', '', '3','5','16','15','7',''),
    April = c('', '', '3','5','','15','','19'),
    May = c('', '8', '3','5','','15','','19'),
    June = c('12', '', '','5','','15','','19'),
    July = c('5', '', '3','5','','15','','19'),
    August = c('51', '', '3','','','15','','19'),
    September = c('5', '', '3','5','','15','','19'),
    October = c('57', '', '','5','','15','','19'),
    November = c('5', '', '','5','','21','','19'),
    December = c('', '', '33','5','','15','','19')
)
Heatmeters[Heatmeters == ''] = NA
Heatmeters[,2:13] = mutate_all(Heatmeters[,2:13], as.numeric)

plot(Heatmeters$Apartment_no, Heatmeters$August)
```

This is the result of the plot...

[image]